# Jquery - Validating only one form out of multiple forms

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

So, I've browsed many threads on SO, but couldnt find my related query. Well, I've a webapp similar to SO, where questions are asked, and people have the liberty to comment/answer on the question (also comments on answers are allowed).

I get the `Answers` of a particular question via the API and form the respective HTML and append it to a div. My HTML is somewhat like this:-

```
<div>
   <p> Some Answer </p>
   <div class="comments"></div>
       <form id="form_62" class="comment_form" method="POST" action="URL"> <!--This id is variable-->
           <textarea rows="3" name="comment"></textarea>
           <button type="submit">Comment </button>
       </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, I append HTML like this in some div DYNAMICALLY. As you can see, there can be many answers, and hence multiple `comments` form.

I wrote a validator against it, which is as follow:-

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('submit', '.comment_form', function(e){
        alert(111)
        form_id = $(this).id
        e.preventDefault();    
        if($(this).valid()){
            $.ajax({
                ...
            });
        }
    })

    $(this).validate({
        ignore: '',
        onsubmit : false,
        rules: {
            comment: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10
            }
        }
    });
})
```

This does not works as expected.

So, my question is how can I validate my current form which is submitted?

Comment: When you say current form, the ID for the form element is what changes, correct?

Comment: yes. It does...

Comment: You will have to use class I believe, see my answer below

Comment: Please show the code that dynamically creates the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any div with form is dynamically added then create one function that apply validate on form based on Id and call function when div or form added dynamically.

```
    function applyValidate(id){
       $(id).validate({
         ignore: '',
         onsubmit : false,
         rules: {
           comment: {
             required: true,
             minlength: 10
           }
         }
      });
   }
```

If all forms are loaded in page at a time and You want to  bind validate on each form then you can use below code.

```js
$(function(){
  $(document).on('submit', '.comment_form', function(e){
    form_id = $(this).id
    e.preventDefault();    
    if($(this).valid()){
      console.log('success')
    }
  });
 
  /* If all forms are not dynamically added and rendered at once in page then you have to apply validate on each form otherwise add applyValidate(id) function outside of $(function(){}); and call applyValidate(id) function when form is dynamically added*/
  
  $('.comment_form').each(function() {  
    // attach to all form elements on page
    $(this).validate({
      ignore: '',
      onsubmit : false,
      rules: {
        comment: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 10
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>


<div>
  <p> Some Answer </p>
  <div class="comments"></div>
  <form id="form_62" class="comment_form" method="POST" action="URL"> <!--This id is variable-->
    <textarea rows="3" name="comment"></textarea>
 <button type="submit">Comment </button>
  </form>
</div>

<div>
  <p> Some Answer </p>
  <div class="comments"></div>
  <form id="form_63" class="comment_form" method="POST" action="URL"> <!--This id is variable-->
    <textarea rows="3" name="comment"></textarea>
 <button type="submit">Comment </button>
  </form>
</div>

<div>
  <p> Some Answer </p>
  <div class="comments"></div>
  <form id="form_64" class="comment_form" method="POST" action="URL"> <!--This id is variable-->
    <textarea rows="3" name="comment"></textarea>
 <button type="submit">Comment </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problems with your code called out in my comments:

```
$(function(){

    // can NOT use submit handler since the validate plugin is already capturing this event
    $(document).on('submit', '.comment_form', function(e){ 

        ....
        // can NOT use 'valid()' before 'validate()' has initialized
        if($(this).valid()){ 
            ....
        }
    })

    // $(this) is meaningless here since it's not inside a pending jQuery method being invoked
    $(this).validate({
        ....
    });
})
```

You would not call `.validate()` when you submit the form.  The `.validate()` method is only used to **initialize** the plugin on your form, not call validation of the form.  So normally `.validate()` is called when the page is loaded.

Since you have forms that do not yet exist when the page is loaded, you would only call `.validate()` **as soon as the dynamic `form` is *created***, not submitted. In other words, invoke the `.validate()` method as the very last step within whatever function creates this form, and since your submit button is a `type="submit"` the validate plugin will capture it automatically and you will not need a `submit` or `click` handler to get validation.

```
$(function(){

    function create_dynamic_form() {

        // code to dynamically create this form HERE


        // initialize validation on this new form ->

        $('#this-new-form-id').validate({
            ....
        });

    });

});
```

My example could be more efficient if you had shown us the actual code that dynamically creates the new form.